# where do i have to pay my extra weight of luggage from Hong Kong to Viet Nam

Tags: luggage

I have 3 luggages bring back to Vietnam from Hongkong, I know now is allow for 30 kilogram per person, but I have 10kilograms over weight, where I can pay for this extra weight?

Comment: It completely depends on the airline.

Answer (score 2):

Some LCC (Low Cost Carriers) airlines allow you to purchase extra baggage online at anytime before your flight. This option is usually listed when you view your reservation online.

Most full service carriers simply charge you when you check in.